# Как конвертировать число длительность в секундах во время часы:минуты:секунды?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дается целое число, которое представляет из себя длительность в секундах одного из мероприятий в компании и проинформирровать об этом в формате часы:минуты:секунды.

Ввод:
Ввод состоит из единственного целого числа `N`.

Вывод:
Конвертируйте данное вам число в часы:минуты:секунды как в следующем примере.

Пример:

```
556

0:9:16

 1

0:0:1

 140153

38:55:53
```

Comment: Если не хочется заниматься программированием, то не надо. Зачем вам это мучение?

Comment: Дополните пожалуйста вопрос попыткой решения.

Answer (score 5):

```
def fun(seconds):
    mn, sc = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hr, mn = divmod(mn, 60)
    return f"{hr}:{mn}:{sc}"
```

---

тесты:

```
In [12]: fun(556)
Out[12]: '0:9:16'

In [13]: fun(140153)
Out[13]: '38:55:53'
```